# Autocomplete field in Django

Tags: django, autocomplete, django-forms

I have models similar to the following:

```
class Country(models.Model):    
        name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

class City(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
        country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
```

and essentially I want to add a City to the database in my template. Before that, i should link it to the Country that already exists, so i want to use 'autocomplete field' in my template to get Country from DB

I have the following form defined:

```
class AddCityForm(forms.ModelForm):
    city_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    country_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
```

In my template i have the forms like this :

```
<form action="/city/add" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
{{ add_city_form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

so is there any solution in django, to make the field 'country_name' autocompleted from the databese ?

cheers,
newbie in django.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. You can check [django-autocomplete](https://code.google.com/p/django-autocomplete/) out

Comment: django-autocomplete's last commit was in 2009. [django-autocomplete-light](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light/) is currently active

Answer (score 6):

As time passes, Django applications rise and fall. There's a grid on `djangopackages.org` that compares various autocompletion solutions and provides hints on their development status: https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/auto-complete/